# Classify the states of the markov chain which is given by two matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains

> Classify the states of the markov chain which is given
>   by these two transition matrices $M_1$ and $M_2:$
>
> $$M_1=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0\\  
> \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\  
> \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2}\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  
> \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;  
> M_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\  
> \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3}\\  
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I think we need to check the properties: rechability, communication and equivalence relation. Is that it or we need to check further properties?

But I'm rather more interested to know *how* you do it on this example because I'm confused we have two matrices given here instead of one. Will I need to individually check those properties for each matrix? And if not both matrices satisfy this property, thus I can conclude the markov chain doesn't satisfy this property?

Say we were checking reachability:

> A state $j$ is reachable from state $i$, if there exists a number $n$
>   such that $p_{ij}(n)>0$

From this definition we see that the markov chain satisfies property reachability because in both matrices there is no column whith only zeroes.

Is this example correct I did?

Comment: I have not seen such a question so far. I think this assumed to be the joint of two questions in one. But your state descriptors are good and you can extract other possible question of interests from them, such as sink state(s), isolated state(s), revisit index(s). P.S.: those names I used in the Finite state automata theory which can be related to Markov chains.

Comment: @SaeidAli Thank you very much for your comment this helps me a lot already! It makes much sense this is two seperate task in one but I didn't realize it myself. Now I think I can solve it :)